# Why is B2C the odd duck and in separate Azure Directory/Tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Why does B2C "live" in its own Azure directory?

This seems to be the odd duck, no?  Are there other Azure services this way?  All of my other Azure resources live in the "default" directory.

[image: change directory screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

It might help in understanding this by understanding the purpose of B2C. The idea here is to support a consumer facing application. For example, you might be building a consumer facing application and people all over the world might access it. You might want to outsource the security piece of that application to Azure AD.

Instead of integrating the application with your corporate Azure AD tenant, you can create a different AD directory, a B2C directory, that simply stores consumer identities. In this case, the B2C AD is completely separate from your corporate / main AD.

Comment: That’s right, B2C users go in the AD directory.  Keeping them separate makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

We all know that for one AAD tenant, it represents an organization. We can use AAD to manage users and resources for an organization. But for AAD B2C, it is just a service for authentication/authorization to all customers which relys application. It can integrate Soical accounts. **AAD B2C cannot define those users belong to one organization.**

However,AAD B2C still needs AAD to do authentication/authorization and manager users. In B2C, users are Local accounts or social accounts. In AAD, users are cloud accounts or on-premise synced accounts.

For example. If we use normal tenant also as a B2C tenant, the AAD authentication/authorization endpoint will be same. With this situation, we cannot distinguish the kind of users.It will result bad logic in product.

For distinguishing this two AAD, the B2C tenant must be separated.

Here is the clarify in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs#can-i-use-azure-ad-b2c-features-in-my-existing-employee-based-azure-ad-tenant):

> Azure AD and Azure AD B2C are separate product offerings and cannot
>   coexist in the same tenant. **An Azure AD tenant represents an
>   organization.** **An Azure AD B2C tenant represents a collection of
>   identities to be used with relying party applications.** With custom
>   policies (in public preview), Azure AD B2C can federate to Azure AD
>   allowing authentication of employees in an organization.

Hope this helps!